# How to modify zeros and poles in a delta-sigma modulator loop?

Tags: adc, control-system, signal-processing, signal-theory

In this specific case, I am modelling a delta-sigma analog-to-digital converter with a basic loop in which the output V is fed back with unity gain to be subtracted from the previously sampled input U (discrete time) and this difference is fed to an integrator modelled with the transfer function:

$$G(z) = \frac{z^{-1}}{1- z^{-1}}$$

[image: 1st order block diagram]

Quantization noise is added in form of error E to the output of the integrator, giving the output V. It follows:

$$V(z)=\frac{G(z)}{1+G(z)}U(z)+\frac{1}{1+G(z)}E(z)$$

The complete model, however, should be a **third-order system** in which the output V is fed back with unity gain twice more so that it is once subtracted from the sampled input in the **outer loop**, this difference is then integrated and fed to the **next loop**, in which the fed-back output is subtracted again. This new delta enters the second integrator and the same process repeats once more in the **inner loop**, where the quantization error is added as described in the first lines above.
In total there will be **2 identical outer loops and a third inner loop** where the quantization is added. In total there will be **3 integrators** with transfer function G.

[image: 3rd order block diagram with gains for poles]

Now I'm interested in the **Noise Transfer Function**: NTF = V / E. According to my computations:

[image: procedure for ntf]
NTF *with gain unity in all three feedback paths* (alpha, beta and gamma are 1) should be equal to:

$$\text{NTF}(z)=\frac{V(z)}{E(z)}=\frac{1}{G(z)^3+3G(z)^2+3G(z)+1}$$

It follows:

$$\text{NTF}(z)=\frac{(z-1)^3}{(z-1)^3+3(z-1)^2+3(z-1)+1}$$

From here, I would like to do two things:

- Replace the poles z1 = 1, z2 = 1 and z3 = 1 of the NTF with different values. In order to do so, I simply introduced a gain factor in the feedback path of each of the three loops (alpha, beta and gamma as above). This will add three coefficients in the denominator that I can play with.

However:

- I would also like to replace two of the zeros of the NTF, which are now all equal to 1, with a pair of **complex conjugate zeros**. This should provide "lower noise around the zeros, at the expense of a less effective shaping at z = 1, thus increasing the usable frequency range".

If I understand correctly, the numerator N(z) of the NTF should be something like this in the end:

$$N(z)=(z-1)(z-e^{jω})(z-e^{-jω})$$

My question is: how do I achieve this? **What should I add in the model to shift the zeros slightly away from DC?**

Just for information: once I have also obtained a pair of complex conjugate zeros, I should solve an optimization problem to find the optimal position of poles and zeros in the NTF for a determinate quantization noise power. So my humble guess is that ideally I should add something as simple as a gain in the model for the zeros, too, so that can adjust the numerator of the NTF, too, and solve for the optimal zeros within certain boundaries.

Comment: It would be helpful if there was a block diagram showing the loops. Would you get zeroes if you tapped each memory element \$1/z\$ in the loops and multiplied them with a gain and added the results to get the final output ? Another method is to simply pass the result of your existing system through an [FIR filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response). FIR filters are some times called *[all-zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter#Direct_form_II)* filters.

Comment: My first intuition is to respond with "zeros of a system cannot be altered with constant feedback". Perhaps dynamic feedback will be your answer. Block diagram helps.

Comment: I don't truly understand where you got NTF(z) from. Could you show us a step-by-step for NTF(z)? The original equation presented in terms of G(z), not already expanded.

Comment: @AJN Could you please explain a little more in detail? Are you suggesting I should add a delay in each feedback path? Please consider I have very limited knowledge of system and control theory. Block diagram and step-by-step NTF added.

Comment: @AndreaToffanin In the second figure showing the three loops, each of the three \$G\$ contain inside it a delay element / memory element represented as \$z^{-1}\$. Either take delay element's output or output of \$G\$ itself. You have three such signals. Multiply each with some coefficient say \$\delta, \pi, \phi\$. Add the results and call *that* V. 1/3...

Comment: 2/3... If you follow [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter#Direct_form_II) which I posted above, you will notice a figure whose middle and left area shows a system with delay elements and feedback (just as you have now). It has some *feed-forward* connections also, each taking output from the delay elements and adding them (\$b_0,b_1,b_2\$ in the figure). It is the *feed-forward* connections which create the zeros of the system.

Comment: 3/3...I am not familiar with your particular system. I will try to write a detailed answer later. Meanwhile, add to your current \$V\$, the outputs of the leftmost two \$G\$ blocks (after multiplying with coefficients) and call this signal your new output \$V′\$. The transfer function for \$V′/E\$ will have zeroes which are dependent on the newly introduced coefficients (and hence configurable). I do not know if this is the easiest way to create zeroes in your system though.

Comment: @AJN I now fully understand your suggestion! If you could complete your answer with a derivation of the NTF with the new numerator N(z) from the new model where the two feed-forward paths have been added, I would be very grateful. I do indeed have a different situation in the numerator now, but I'm not sure it's correct. I guess, the newly added coefficients should be chosen adequately, too, to obtain that specific numerator.
Remark: alpha, beta and gamma feedback paths should be negative, the minus sign is missing at the summations in my second picture

Comment: [In this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_biquad_filter#Transposed_Direct_form_2) I searched for *implementations* where the multiple taps are made from the output (`Y(z)` in the article, `V` in your question). Direct form 2 (Transposed version) matches that criteria. But to create numerator polynomials in that form multiple signal taps are required on the input (`E` in your NTF case), but since `E` is usually an unknown (noise), I don't think it will work out. However, all the implementations shown in this article represent the same transfer function. contd...

Comment: contd...  If you can transform your block diagram into one of the other forms where one need not tap signals directly from `E`, you may be able to create zeroes at desired locations. Since I am not familiar with this type of ADC or its analyses, I am not in a position to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can achieve "placeable zeros" is by using a dynamic feedback. As given in the question, this is what you achieved with constant feedback on three loops:
$$G(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}$$
$$\text{NTF(z)}=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{z-1}\right)\left(1+\frac{\beta}{z-1}\right)\left(1+\frac{\gamma}{z-1}\right)}$$
$$\text{NTF(z)}=\frac{(z-1)^3}{(z-1+\alpha)(z-1+\beta)(z-1+\gamma)}$$

Now see what happens when replacing constant feedback for dynamic feedbacks with pole-zero cancelation:
$$A(z)=\alpha\frac{z-1}{z-\lambda_1}$$
$$B(z)=\beta\frac{z-1}{z-\lambda_2}$$
$$C(z)=\gamma\frac{z-1}{z-\lambda_3}$$
$$\text{NTF(z)}=\frac{1}{\left(1+A(z)G(z)\right)\left(1+B(z)G(z)\right)\left(1+C(z)G(z)\right)}$$
$$\text{NTF(z)}=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{z-\lambda_1}\right)\left(1+\frac{\beta}{z-\lambda_2}\right)\left(1+\frac{\gamma}{z-\lambda_3}\right)}$$
$$\text{NTF(z)}=\frac{(z-\lambda_1)(z-\lambda_2)(z-\lambda_3)}{(z-\lambda_1+\alpha)(z-\lambda_2+\beta)(z-\lambda_3+\gamma)}$$

With this, you have achieve three real "placeable zeros" at \$\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\$ and three real placeable poles at \$\lambda_1-\alpha,\lambda_2-\beta,\lambda_3-\gamma\$. In order to achieve complex zeros, at least one of the feedback loops would have to be of second order. I also believe you will need only two feedback loops instead of three, but perhaps other arrangements are possible:
$$A(z)=0$$
$$B(z)=\beta\frac{z-1}{z-\lambda_1}$$
$$C(z)=\gamma\frac{z-1}{\left(z-\lambda_2e^{j\theta}\right)\left(z-\lambda_2e^{-j\theta}\right)}$$
$$\text{NTF(z)}=\frac{1}{\left(1+0\right)\left(1+\frac{\beta}{z-\lambda_1}\right)\left(1+\frac{\gamma}{\left(z-\lambda_2e^{j\theta}\right)\left(z-\lambda_2e^{-j\theta}\right)}\right)}$$
$$\text{NTF(z)}=\frac{\left(z-\lambda_1\right)\left(z-\lambda_2e^{j\theta}\right)\left(z-\lambda_2e^{-j\theta}\right)}{\left(z-\lambda_1+\beta\right)\left(\left(z-\lambda_2e^{j\theta}\right)\left(z-\lambda_2e^{-j\theta}\right)+\gamma\right)}$$